# Match against not fetching result on 3 digits number

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on match against SQL on phpmyadmin

this is my query

```
SELECT `[tableName]`.* FROM `[tableName]` 
WHERE 
(MATCH(`[col1]`, `[col2]`, `[col3]`, `[col4]`) AGAINST ('2014' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (type IN('[firstValue]', '[secondValue]')) ORDER BY MATCH(`[col1]`, `[col2]`, `[col3]`, `[col4]`) AGAINST ('2014') DESC
```

when i run this query it returns the result against it. 
but when i run the following query the result is empty

```
SELECT `[tableName]`.* FROM `[tableName]` 
WHERE 
(MATCH(`[col1]`, `[col2]`, `[col3]`, `[col4]`) AGAINST ('107' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (type IN('[firstValue]', '[secondValue]')) ORDER BY MATCH(`[col1]`, `[col2]`, `[col3]`, `[col4]`) AGAINST ('107') DESC
```

I have confirmed that there is data against 107 in the table and i can fetch it in phpmyadmin using like '%107%'.

I think the data is not fetched or matched with the number is three digits as i changed 2014 to 201 and search for it. It was also not showing.

Kindly help what could be the possible issue with this query or server settings or anything. I have tried everything I know and now I'm stuck.

Comment: a) Searching for `201` will not give you `2014`, as this will only find complete words, `201*` should find it though. b) A fulltext index has a minimum word length. Everything shorter is not included in the index. Innodbs `ft-min-word-len`-value defaults to 4, which would explain your behaviour. Check it. If you change it, you have to rebuild your indexes for the new value to be used.

Comment: I get your second point. But for the first point to clarify what i meant was in database i changed the value 2014 with 201 and then i try to find it. But my query could'n found it. It's not like i'm trying to find 2014 with 201.